# If the dependent variable in a multiple regression is not normally distributed

Tags: regression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regression on a non-normal dependent variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11256/regression-on-a-non-normal-dependent-variable)

If the dependent variable in a multiple regression is not normally distributed, what can be done to correct it?

Comment: If $Y$ is your outcome and ${\bf X}$ are your predictors then there is no assumption that $Y$ has a normal distribution. The inference in a least squares model does assume that $Y|{\bf X}$ has a normal distribution. This is a subtle but very important difference (as well as a common misunderstanding).

Comment: This is a popular question which has been asked (and answered) in many forms previously.  E.g., search on your key words (such as "dependent +normal +regression") or look at one of the first hits, such as http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11256/regression-on-a-non-normal-dependent-variable.  Pay most attention to the *advice* in the replies rather than the details of the circumstances, which vary slightly.